# Start up a tablet PC per schedule

Tags: windows, mobile-devices

I would like to start up a couple of tablet PCs per schedule. The Tablets should be started up i.e. at 8 am automatically. Then I can shut them down trough the windows-schedule. The tablets are running Windows 8.1.

I know usually I would do this trough the BIOS. This tablet from ASUS doesn't have almost ANY options in it's BIOS. You can technically just set the time and Boot-Order there.

Is there a way to start up the tablets automatically without this BIOS setting? Is there maybe a way I can add the BIOS setting? (Maybe Updating the BIOS is a possibility).

The tablet is an ASUS Transformer Book.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, why?  Why bother shutting down computers in the first place, and then, why auto-start them on a schedule?  This is a silly requirement you should probably reconsider.

Having said that, [wake-on-LAN is probably the best way to pull this off on a consumer device](http://lifehacker.com/348197/access-your-computer-anytime-and-save-energy-with-wake+on+lan).  You should be able to setup or script a scheduled task to issue a WoL packet to the computer every morning at 08:00.  EDIT: since you mention the lack of an Ethernet port on these tablets as a problem in your comment, you might want to take a look at [Wake on Wireless LAN (WoWLAN)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851581%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), which is apparently a thing, and possibly applicable to your situation.

I'll also point out that if you're willing to just hibernate the computers instead of shutting them down, you can use the built-in Windows task scheduler to schedule hibernation **and** wake-up times, which is probably easier than setting up WoL.

Comment: ...and considering these tablets don't have a Ethernet NIC and Wake-On-Wireless-LAN is very rare, hibernation is probably a better bet.

Comment: It is due to the problem we have tested that PCs get slower over time. The solution will be used in a rough factory environment and tablets will be used as an "intelligence" for big displays for the workers of the factory. Wake-On-LAN is not possible due to the tablets missing Ethernet connector. This requirement is because the factory workers wont be able to shut down the tablets themselves. Shutting down is not a problem, just waking them up. Furthermore I want to tell you your answer is not constructive. You don't know the whole process and requirement behind the solution to call it silly.

Comment: @tombull89 My (Dell) transformer tablet has an Ethernet port.  I guess I just assumed that other transformer tablets did too... although, to be technical, you could (potentially) [use Wake on Wireless LAN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851581%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) if the lack of an Ethernet port is your only problem with WoL.

Comment: @ElMac The point is more that it's silly to turn these things off, or have to jump through technical hoops to accomplish the trivial task of pressing a power button when a user starts their shift.  Either way, whether you agree that it's "silly" or not, you've been provided with two methods of accomplishing what asked about - WoLAN/WoWLAN, or hibernation and a scheduled wake-up task, so calling the answer not constructive is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Apparently this tablet PC does not support anything like that. Maybe I will just order other tablets. Thanks for the support, if you have other ideas just let me know!
The display is attached to the display on the ceiling of the building. The user can not reach it.

Comment: @ElMac  Any reason hibernation isn't an option?  It's almost the same thing as powering it off, and to be completely honest, I'm not sure that my tablet's ever been completely powered off.  It hibernates when I'm not using it, and wakes up when I do use it.  Other than reboots for patching, and occasionally running out of power because I haven't plugged it in for a week, it doesn't get rebooted or powered off, and it still works fine.